# Xamarin IOS Embed UITableView with Static Cells in another View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, storyboard, uikit

I'm designing a multipaged IPad app using Xamarin.IOS in Visual Studio for Mac. Page design has been done with storyboards and I'm trying to design a page, let's call it TablePage, the contains a UITableView which will cover about half of the screen, the other half of the screen will contain other controls. This table needs to be created with static cells, which requires a UITableViewController.

I've already added in the UITableView and proper constraints to TablePage, and now I've added a UITableViewController into my storyboard where I will design each cell and their behaviors. My question is how do I tell the UITableView in TablePage that it will be populated and controlled by my new controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use special views (container views) that manage some other UIViewController.

Instead of your UITableView add Container View and add root segue from this container view to your UITableViewController. You can set constraints for container view to specify its size, and customize UITableView inside your UITableViewController.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you! For anyone else having the same issue, I deleted the UIViewController automatically created by the UIContainerView and ctrl dragged from the container to my UITableViewController to embed